# Building a List in actions-on-google Nodejs v2

Tags: actions-on-google

I may be missing something really obvious, but I haven't figured out how I can build a List programatically in v2 of tne actions-on-google Nodejs client library.

In other words, I want to do something like the conv.ask code below, but don't know the items beforehand, so need to create a list, add the items to the list, and then ask the list in dynamic way. I could do this in v1 with:

```
var rList = app.buildList("Please select one option:");
for (var r =0; r < resp_text.length; r++) {
  rList.addItems(app.buildOptionItem(resp_value[r], resp_matches[r]).setTitle(resp_text[r]));
}
app.askWithList(question_str, rList);
```

... so am basically looking for the v2 equivalent  of the above.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

```
conv.ask(new List({
    title: 'Things to learn about',
    items: {
      // Add the first item to the list
      'MATH_AND_PRIME': {
        synonyms: [
          'math',
          'math and prime',
          'prime numbers',
          'prime',
        ],
        title: 'Title of the First List Item',
        description: '42 is an abundant number',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://example.com/math_and_prime.jpg',
          alt: 'Math & prime numbers',
        }),
      },
      // Add the second item to the list
      'EGYPT': {
        synonyms: [
          'religion',
          'egypt',
          'ancient egyptian',
      ],
        title: 'Ancient Egyptian religion',
        description: '42 gods ruled on the fate of the dead in the afterworld',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'http://example.com/egypt',
          alt: 'Egypt',
        }),
      },
      // Add the last item to the list
      'RECIPES': {
        synonyms: [
          'recipes',
          'recipe',
          '42 recipes',
        ],
        title: '42 recipes in 42 ingredients',
        description: 'A beautifully simple recipe',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'http://example.com/recipe',
          alt: 'Recipe',
        }),
      },
    },
  }));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, answering my own question just in case it will help someone else...

The way (or at least one way) to do this is to dynamicaly create an item array and using that in the list constructor:

```
 var ritems = {}
 for (var r=0; r < resp_text.length; r++) {
     ritems[resp_value[r]] = {
         synonyms: [resp_matches[r]],
         title: resp_text[r]
     }
 }
 conv.ask(question_str);
 conv.ask(new List({
     title: "Please select one option:",
     items: ritems
 }))
```

Comment: Did this actually work? Also, did you manage to sort out how to show the image on each entry? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, works perfectly, although I had no need for images, so didn't try that part.